# Javascipt to count increment price for each tier

Tags: javascript, increment

I am new to coding and currently touch the javascript part. I am facing a question about how to calculate the different tier prices and charges as shown in the image: [Tier Pricing Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HMzg.png)

This is the code that I have tried. `i` represents the LOAN AMOUNT tier. When `i` is equal to 1 it will use the next tier percentage to count and the i will +1 ag, but I am not sure is it correct or not... And should I add a EventListener to determine which tier the input now is? Sorry for my broken English. Thanks a lot! ^_^

`if(loan >= 500000 && loan < 1000000 && i==0) charge = 1% i = 1`

`if(loan >= 500000 && loan < 1000000 && i==1) charge = 0.8% i = 2`

`if(loan >= 2000000 && loan < 2000000 && i==2) charge = 0.7% i = 3`

`if(loan >= 2000000 && loan < 2000000 && i==3) charge = 0.6% i= 4`

Comment: Try it with ```switch``` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what your goal is, but if you want a system like tax brackets, where the loan amount is charged in portions based on the remaining money and where it fits in a tier it might look a little like this:

```js
const getChargedSums = (amount) => {
  let loanAmount = amount;
  let sums = [];
  
  loanAmount -= 500000; 
    if (loanAmount < 0) {
    sums.push((loanAmount + 500000) * 0.1)
    return sums
  }
  sums.push(500000 * 0.1)

  loanAmount -= 500000; 
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
    sums.push((loanAmount + 500000) * 0.08)
    return sums
  }
  sums.push(500000 * 0.08)
   
  loanAmount -= 2000000; 
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
    sums.push((loanAmount + 2000000) * 0.07)
    return sums
  }
  sums.push(2000000 * 0.07)

  loanAmount -= 2000000;
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
    sums.push((loanAmount + 2000000) * 0.06)
    return sums
  }
  sums.push(2000000 * 0.06)

  loanAmount -= 25000000; 
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
    sums.push((loanAmount + 25000000) * 0.05)
    return sums
  }
  sums.push(25000000 * 0.05)

  sums.push(loanAmount * 0.05)
  return sums
}
let chargedSums = getChargedSums(800000)
console.log('Charged:', chargedSums.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
```

Comment: Sorry just back from work.Thanks Isaac. What I need is 
Example:3,500,000= (1st 500,000 * 1%) + (2nd 500,000*0.8%) + (2,000,000 * 0.7%) + (500,000 * 0.6%) 
In this case , which solution I should use? Is it the first one?Thanks

loanAmount -= 500000; 
  i.push(1)
  percents.push(1)  
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
     return {i, percents}
  } loanAmount -= 500000; 
  i.push(1)
  percents.push(1)  
  if (loanAmount < 0) {
     return {i, percents}
  }

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your needs, take a look and see if that works

Comment: Thanks Isaac . I can understand those statement which use to determine which % the loanAmount should use and which stage now the loanAmount is with the -= **condition** and + **condition** to * the % . But the 1st 3 line code I not really understand ,can u explain to me? My <input> in html id should be chargedSums?based on the last two line code. But the result id in html is? cause the last line code is also using chargedSums to display the value

Comment: If possible, please provide your HTML code in your original post